# Thevenin equivalent circuit of dependent sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I'm trying to figure out the thevenin equivalent circuit of this

[image]

There's a hint to use a voltage test, which I did. I know the Vth = 0 since there are no independent sources in the circuit. But I don't know how to get the Rth which is still confusing to me because I don't know where to start when finding the Rth of the circuit.

The voltage test I used is 1V.

Comment: Simply used the test voltage ( Vtest = 1V) and calculated the test voltage current Itest. And the Rth is equal to Rth = Vtest/Itest

Comment: You can also inject a 1 A current to find out. But you don't need to do anything of the sort. You have \$21\,i_\Delta\$ in parallel with a resistor presenting \$1\,i_\Delta\$. So it is obvious that the \$21\,i_\Delta\$ source is \$\frac{700}{21}\Omega\$. The total current then in that parallel pair is  \$22\,i_\Delta\$. This flows through a voltage source of \$300\,i_\Delta\$. So that too is a resistor: \$=\frac{300}{22}\Omega\$. Clearly, the whole thing is replaced by a single resistor of \$\left[\left(700\mid\mid\frac{700}{21}\right)+\frac{300}{22}\right]\mid\mid10\approx 8.197\:\Omega\$.

Comment: @periblepsis Please don't hand out complete solutions to obvious homework questions.